# CSS variables with arithmetic operations don’t work in shorthand properties?

Tags: css, shorthand, css-calc, css-variables

Please help me to find out why an arithmetic operation in CSS variable breaks the code.

I began with a simple CSS file with one rule:

```
html {
  font: 16px/32px Arial;
}
```

In browsers, it works as written: the font size is 16px, the line height is 32px, and the font itself is Arial.

Then I added the variables:

```
html {
  --default-font-size: 16px;
  --default-line-height: var(--default-font-size);
  font: var(--default-font-size)/var(--default-line-height) Arial;
}
```

It works, too; thought the line height is 16px, because I made it equal to the font size.

But when I multiplicated the second value, the font declaration stopped working:

```
html {
  --default-font-size: 16px;
  --default-line-height: var(--default-font-size) * 2;
  font: var(--default-font-size)/var(--default-line-height) Arial;  /* not working! */
}
```

All the properties `font-size`, `line-height`, and `font-family` are set to browser defaults.

If I split `font` shorthand property into three different longhand properties, the code works OK again:

```
html {
  --default-font-size: 16px;
  --default-line-height: var(--default-font-size) * 2;
  font-size: var(--default-font-size);
  line-height: var(--default-line-height);
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

What is wrong with the previous code sample and is there a way to make it work without splitting into longhand properties?

Comment: are you sure the third one is working ? it should not be too

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you’re right, it works partially: the `font-size` and `font-family` are set, but `line-height` isn’t.

Comment: yes in this case it's logic, the line-height should not work in the third case too ... it needs the `calc` function too ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `calc` like this :

```
html {
  --default-font-size: 16px;
  --default-line-height: calc(var(--default-font-size) * 2);
  font: var(--default-font-size)/var(--default-line-height) Arial;
}
```

The `--default-line-height` is replaced in the `font` property before getting evalutated so you have something like this (**not valid**) :

```
font: var(--default-font-size)/var(--default-font-size) * 2 Arial;
```

By the use of `calc` you evalute the expression and you have a valid syntax. Even your third example will not work. The CSS doesn't recognize the multiplication sign as it should be used inside a `calc`

```css
p {
  --default-font-size: 16px;
  --default-line-height: calc(var(--default-font-size) * 4);
  font: var(--default-font-size)/var(--default-line-height) Arial;
}
```

```html
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: But this code seems not to work **in Firefox only**, while working in other browsers. Is it code’s or Firefox’s fault?

`:root {
      --grid-spacing: 12px;
      --font-size-default: calc(var(--grid-spacing) * 4/3);
      --line-height-default: calc(var(--grid-spacing) * 2);
    }

    html {
      font: var(--font-size-default)/var(--line-height-default) Arial;
    }`

Comment: Apparently there must be blank spaces around the operator.